# How to set Viewport Range via values at MpAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have dataset values at range [0-10000]. 
And I want to see range [500-600] at chart with automatically calculated scroll and zoom values. 
How it can be done in MPAndroidChart?

Is there any method to setXRange(leftXValue, rightXValue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the max visible range. 
So if you want to display the range of 500-600, set a max visible range of 100

```
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100);
```

than you have to move your view so that the values are visible from the 500th position

```
mChart.moveViewToX(499);
```

Comment: `setVisibleXRangeMaximum` prevents any further zooming beyond the given value, which may be a problem depending on exactly what you need. So, after calling `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100)` and `moveViewToX(499)` you might want to then reset the available zoom level using `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10000)`