# MPAndroidChart set current visible X axis

Tags: android, zooming, viewport, mpandroidchart, pan

Using MPAndroidChart, I'm struggling to figure out how to set the current visible x axis values. The use case is simple and I would have thought very common, so I'm sure I must be missing some function which can do this:

- Say you have a chart with x axis values 1-100
- A user zooms and pans a chart so that the range 60-80 is visible. I want to store these values, so that tomorrow when the user re-launches the app, I can restore the exact viewing state (60-80)

Storing the values is really easy - you can simply call `chart.lowestVisibleX` and `chart.highestVisibleX` to get the x axis values. But how do I set them on a new instance of the chart? Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a `chart.setHighestVisibleX` or `chart.setLowestVisibleX`.

[This previous question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930860/how-to-set-viewport-range-via-values-at-mpandroidchart?rq=1) is nearly, but not quite, what I need. The suggestion is to use a combination of `chart.moveViewToX(60)` and `chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20)`. However as the docs for `setVisibleXRangeMaximum` state:

> Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be maximum
>   visible at once (no further zooming out allowed)

I don't want to prevent further zooming, which is what this does. There must be a way to set the zoom level without actually restricting further zooming - but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer my own question, I decided to workaround this issue by resetting the X range maximum after calling `moveViewToX`. This appears to work. So the solution would be:

```
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20)
chart.moveViewToX(60)
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100)
```